# Get human readable time from react native datetime picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datetimepicker

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import RNDateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const Timer = ({}) => {
    const [picker, setPicker] = React.useState({time: null, date: null});
    const [mode, setMode] = React.useState(null);

    const setTimer = (event, time) => {
         if (mode == 'date') {
             if (time) setPicker(e => ({...e, date: time}));
             setMode('time');
         } else if (time && picker.date ) {
             setPicker(e => ({...e, time: time}));
             // do something here   
        }
    }

    const humanReadable = () => {/* return human readable date time format (2022/05:31 13:59:00) */}

    return (
        <>
             <Text>{ humanReadable() }</Text>
             <Button value="Get Date & Time" onPress={() => setMode("date")} />
             { 
                 mode && (
                     <RNDateTimePicker 
                           onChange={setTimer} 
                           mode={mode}
                           display={mode=='date' ? "calendar" : "clock"}
                           themeVariant="light" 
                           value={picker[mode] ?? new Date()} 
                     />
                 )
             }
        </>
    )
}
```

Beacuse i m working on android. So i have no option for set mode "datetime". That is why i have added here this.
My question is how to get human readable datetime

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at this lib https://date-fns.org

Here's how I use it :

```
//IMPORT FIRST 
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { fr } from 'date-fns/locale';

//THEN IN YOUR JSX
           <Text>
           {format(dateValue, 'dd MMMM yyyy', { locale: fr })}
           </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Its an amazing module to format date. Please have a look at it.

For your format you can do something like,

```js
import moment from 'moment';

moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).